# How to find the current translate position in Canvas?

Tags: android, canvas

How do I get the current translate position from a Canvas? I am trying to draw stuff where my coordinates are a mix of relative (to each other) and absolute (to canvas).

Lets say I want to do

```
canvas.translate(x1, y1);
canvas.drawSomething(0, 0); // will show up at (x1, y1), all good
// now i want to draw a point at x2,y2
canvas.translate(x2, y2);
canvas.drawSomething(0, 0); // will show up at (x1+x2, y1+y2)
// i could do
canvas.drawSomething(-x1, -y1);
// but i don't always know those coords
```

This works but is dirty:

```
private static Point getCurrentTranslate(Canvas canvas) {
    float [] pos = new float [2];
    canvas.getMatrix().mapPoints(pos);
    return new Point((int)pos[0], (int)pos[1]);
}
...
Point p = getCurrentTranslate(canvas);
canvas.drawSomething(-p.x, -p.y);
```

The canvas has a getMatrix method, it has a `setTranslate` but no `getTranslate`. I don't want to use `canvas.save()` and `canvas.restore()` because the way I'm drawing things it's a little tricky (and probably messy ...)

Is there a cleaner way to get these current coordinates?

Answer (score 1):

You need to reset the transformation matrix first.  I'm not an android developer, looking at the [android canvas docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html), there is no reset matrix, but there is a setMatrix(android.graphics.Matrix).  It says if the given matrix is null it will set the current matrix to the identity matrix, which is what you want.  So I think you can reset your position (and scale and skew) with:

```
canvas.setMatrix(null);
```

It would also be possible to get the current translation through getMatrix.  There is a mapVectors() method you could use for [matrices](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Matrix.html) to see where the point [0,0] would be mapped to, this would be your translation.  But in your case I think resetting the matrix is best.